# BinaryJS alternative? Multiplexing streams between browser and server over websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, websocket

I need to multiplex a couple streams between the browser and a Node.js server over a single Websocket connection.  One stream is going to be used for sending binary data from the browser to the server, and the other is going to be used for [a simple RPC](https://github.com/dominictarr/rpc-stream).

I stumbled across [BinaryJS](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs) which does exactly what I want.  However, it has a [specific problem with binary data](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/issues/63) and doesn't appear to be maintained regularly.  Is there an alternative?  My requirements:

- Binary-compatible (no JSON serialization of binary data... that takes a ton of bandwidth)
- Supports multiple, bidirectional streams

I actually don't care so much about browser support.  My application relies on other modern APIs, so I'm only targeting current versions of Chrome and Firefox.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can open multiple WebSocket connections form a website. I would recommend you to use different protocols in this case to tell them apart from each other on the server. How to do this on the server depends on what technology you want to use.

Comment: @Philipp I'm opening multiple connections now.  I only want to open a single connection and multiplex the streams through it.  Many mobile networks enforce connection limits on devices, and when you go over it anything from throttling to connection failures occur.  One less connection to worry about (and then one less connection to have to monitor the state of and open/close simultaneously) is better.

Answer (score 3):

Brad I fixed the typed array issue with BinaryJS you were experiencing (in version 0.2.0). But you're right I haven't had much time to maintain it so you may run into other issues.